# How can I get my div to be on the same line as my header?

Tags: css, html

HTML:

```
<h2> RAN sends fake news report on Hershey's Oil Commitment</h2>   
<div class="date">  
<div class="number">27</div>
<div class="month">Oct</div>  </div> 
<p>The Rainforest Action Network sent out a fake news report about Hershey's Oil   
Commitment. It stated that Hershey will remove palm oil from all of their products and 
a few news sites fell for it including Hershey's own hometown newspaper. On top of  
that, the people from RAN crashed Hershey's Halloween party with a very special   
orangutan! 
<a href="hershey.html">Want to know more?</a> </p>
```

CSS:

```
.date {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:orange;
  border-radius:1em;
  margin-left:75%;
}

.number {
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.month {
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#E68A00;
  color:white;
}

h2 {
  font-size:1.2em;
  color:#007e7e;
}
```

I'm trying to get the date and the title of the news article to be on the same line. This is what it looks like now:

[image: News Article]

Comment: Can the HTML be modified?

Comment: @jvperrin Newusers can't upload images. When you're suggesting an edit, and the image is valid, could you please upload it for them to: http://i.stack.imgur.com That way the image link will last forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 {
font-size:1.2em;
color:#007e7e; 
float:left;
}
```

Add a float left to the header - it will cause the next div to float left on the same line as the h2.

You can also add a float:right to the div, but that will make the div appear on the far right end of its container.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I was missing something so simple :P

Answer (score 0):

put the date and the title in the same div/container and float the to the left + use clearfix to avoid parent container size issues.

or simply position them relatively using left / top

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to the h2 and `float:right` to .date like so: http://jsfiddle.net/DAWQ4/2/

```
<h2> RAN sends fake news report on Hershey's Oil Commitment</h2><div class="date">  
<div class="number">27</div>
<div class="month">Oct</div>  </div> <br><br>
<p>The Rainforest Action Network sent out a fake news report about Hershey's Oil   
Commitment. It stated that Hershey will remove palm oil from all of their products and 
a few news sites fell for it including Hershey's own hometown newspaper. On top of  
that, the people from RAN crashed Hershey's Halloween party with a very special   
orangutan! 
<a href="hershey.html">Want to know more?</a> </p>




.date {
float:right;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:orange;
border-radius:1em;
}

.number {
color:white;
text-align:center; }

.month {
text-align:center;
background-color:#E68A00;
color:white; }

h2 {
    float:left;
font-size:1.2em;
color:#007e7e; }

p {
clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DAWQ4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to fix it:
in your CSS

```
h2{
    float: left;
}
.date{
    float:right;
}
p {
    clear:both;
}
```

Floating the h2 takes it out of it's natural flow and then when you float the .date it takes that out of it's natural html flow (which was causing it to be below the h2) and because you've floated the h2 left and the .date right, they sit next to eachother.  The clear: both; makes it so that the paragraph text doesn't get so close and cover any other empty space (which there is a little) so it leaves it basically where it was.